# How to hide a column in a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Here, I found once the code to hide a repeater column easily. It works great like this.

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1" /></td>
            <% if (MustBeVisible) { %>
            <td"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="label2" /></td>
            <% } %>
      </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

But now, I need to apply a CLASS to the TableRow and make it runat="server" in order to apply a color condition in the ItemDataBound but when I add the attribute of runat="server" I have a conflict at runtime and a warning.

> ASP.NET runtime error: Code blocks are not supported in this context

The idea is, for example, to evaluate in the ItemDataBound the label1, if it's true must apply a Class on TR to make it grey.

Any idea of the best approach or how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

First, Define a bool property, say `ShouldBeGreyed` in your data-item class (if possible). This property should return whether the data-item will be greyed out or not.

Then, Use this in your repeater markup:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr<%# ((bool)Eval("ShouldBeGreyed"))?"class='grey'":"" %>>
    ...
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Approach 2:**

First, define a method in code-behind, say `ShouldBeGreyed`, like this:

```
protected bool ShouldBeGreyed(object item)
{
    // cast to your data-item
    var dataItem = (<class-of-your-data-item>)item;

    // Determine if it should be greyed out
    // bool shouldBeGreyed = ...
    ...

    return shouldBeGreyed;
}
```

Now use this in your repeater markup:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr<%# ((bool)ShouldBeGreyed(Container.DataItem))?"class='grey'":"" %>>
    ...
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this.. Write the method in the Visible portion of the label.

```
 <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="label2" Visible="<%# MustBeVisible() %>" /></td>
```

if you want the `td` to be invisible/visible use this

```
 <td runat="server visible="<%# MustBeVisible() %>"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="label2" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you made the `<td id="tablerow" runat="server"/>` could you use do something like:

```
tablerow.Attributes.Add("class", className);
```